# R: assignment of dataframe element inside with statement

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to assign to the elements of a dataframe, but don't want to type something like `df$x` every time because **the name of the dataframe can be very long**. Also, I don't want to use `attach`, so I turn to the `with` statement. However, I cannot get it to work (please see the following code):

```
> df <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=5:1)
> with(df, {x[1]<-10
+ x[1]})
[1] 10
> df$x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I assigned 10 to the 1st element of `df$x` inside the `with` "statement", and it looked fine inside. However, once outside of `with`, `df$x` did not seem to be changed.

**My questions** are: How can I make it work inside `with` (or `within`)? If this is not possible, are there any alternatives (besides `attach`)?

Comment: Why do you need it to do this way?  `df$x[1] <- 10` would be more direct.  If you need to use `df <- with(df, {x[1]<-10;x})` assign it to the original dataset

Comment: Just read the part `name of the dataframe can be very long`.  Even in that case, wouldn't `with(verylongdataname,..` be asking to type a lot?

Comment: FWIW, you can pass the `$` a partial column name, and as long as it's distinct, it's fine. As far as I know, the only way around a data.frame name would be to copy and rename it.

Comment: You need to assign your `with` call back to somewhere. `with` isn't modifying your variables in place. Take a look into `transform` (which is also required to be assigned back) but returns a whole data set instead of just the column. Also `within` could be interesting for you.

Comment: if you are ok typing the data frame name only one time, you can try the package data.table. `library(data.table);dt <- as.data.table(df); dt[1,x:=10]`

Comment: @CarlosAlberto why not `setDT`? Why copying the whole data set? That kind of missing the whole point IMO.

Comment: I should express my self better: I was thinking that the data frame was worked as a data.table from the very beginning, so when the assignment is required a very short instruction can do the job: just `dt[1,x:=10]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with` returns the value of the evaluated expr, in this case the modified value of x. So you'd need to use `within` instead as it returns the modified object.

I think the problem you're also facing is that you're not assigning to anything so

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=5:1)
within(df, {x[1] <- 10})
```

is returning

```
x y
10 5
2 4
3 3
4 2
5 1
```

but then `df` returns

```
x y
1 5
2 4
3 3
4 2
5 1
```

So you'd need something like

```
df <- within(df, {x[1] <- 10})
```

which doesn't really help your long data frame name problem much. So how about

```
df[1, "x"] <- 10
```

which is only typing it once or temporarily rename the data frame to something shorter?

Comment: `x[1]<-10` is actually a MWE. What I really want to do with the data frame is more like `  for (t in seq(5, 3000))
  {
    xt <- two.species$x[t-1]
    yt <- two.species$y[t-1]
    two.species$rx[t] <- 3.1 * xt * (1 - xt) * exp(-0.3 * t.series[t])
    two.species$ry[t] <- 2.9 * yt * (1 - yt) * exp(-0.36 * t.series[t])
    rxt <- two.species$rx[t-4]
    ryt <- two.species$ry[t-4]
    two.species$x[t] <- 0.4*xt + max(rxt, 0)
    two.species$y[t] <- 0.35*yt + max(ryt, 0)
  }`

Comment: Also, I wonder if `df <- within(df, {x[1] <- 10})` will trigger a copying of the data frame?

Answer (score 2):

As previously posted... work with data.table.

```
library(data.table)
```

as soon as you read your data.frame, convert it to a data.table

```
dt <- data.table(df)
```

and then will just be:

```
dt[1,x:=10]
```

Comment: Again, you can convert in place using `setDT` instead of creating a copy. See `?setDT`.

Comment: Something new to learn. Thanks. However, base on the problem as explained ("don't want to type something like `df$x` every time"), I assumed that he has to do similar operations several times. Then, a full conversion from the beginning will work better.

Answer (score 1):

`within` is what you're looking for.

```
within(df, {
  x[1] <- 10
})

   x y
1 10 5
2  2 4
3  3 3
4  4 2
5  5 1
```

Comment: You will still need to assign back to `df`, otherwise you are back at square one like OP had with `with`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I thought that was self-explanatory.

Comment: If it was, OP would figure it with `with` too, no? But he was thinking `with` is modifying in place for some reason.